# SCD2 on flatfile sink in adf

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a scenario where in my source and target both are flat files. I want to implement SCD-2 on target flat file using dataflow. I was trying to use alter row then sink but later realized the sink for flat file doesn't give option for update row options. Is there any workaround for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not for text flat files. But you can do this by using Delta as the dataset format in the sink if Parquet / Delta output is acceptable in your use case.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evqQRwsF_Ps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-data-flow-delta-lake

Comment: Thanks Mark, I am able to do. I was trying to implement SCD2, how to make single target table as its keep on creating new table every time. Any suggestion please, thank you.

Comment: In Delta, your folder path in ADLS will be your table. Use an Alter Row transformation to decide whether to insert, update, or delete rows.